# What algorithm or pattern to use to check what rows in what tables will be cascade deleted in mysql/pgsql?

Tags: java, mysql, algorithm, postgresql, design-patterns

So the question - I have a lot of tables in database and almost all of them have on delete cascade. What is the best way to inform user what will be deleted in entire database if he deletes one certain row. What algorithm/patterns should I read? It's desirable with implementation in java. Thank you.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but they best way that I know of to deal with cascading deletes is to disable the delete cascade and create a data admin tool that is user friendly.

Comment: @DwB Thank you for your time. Usual user can't delete. He can only mark for deletion. Admin can. But it's really long to delete all foreign key links.

Comment: In PostgreSQL you can do this by querying the `information_schema` to build a graph of foreign key relationships with cascade options. A recursive CTE (`WITH RECURSIVE`) should do it. Of course that only works if your ORM actually generates proper foreign key relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this seems like a wrong design when you consider the fact that the cascade paths through the object graph are known at compile time and you are asking how to construct them, on demand, at runtime. You could build them and store them once.

That said, there probably isn't much reason for a design pattern. Mostly you are going to need Reflection, including the ability to find annotations on either properties or methods.

Then as you navigate the graph, you will look for the target annotations and either add or not add, and of course, if you don't find a cascade, you can stop going down that branch of the graph.

If there were some reason to handle types differently, Visitor would apply, but there isn't. The annotation processing tool from Sun used visitor, but that was for compile time processing.

Probably don't have the ability to do this, but it would be interesting to do it in Java 8 because you could more cleanly separate the navigation code from the test code, by defining a Predicate (as a Lambda) and then just having that be evaluated at each node. Your predicate would simple check for the presence of the Cascade annotation. Sounds like maybe you are not using an ORM so might not have annotations in your code for the cascades, all the more reason to have a separate predicate because then you could have a metadata version that actually looks at the specific database (Postgres), but if you wanted to use it with an ORM, you'd literally be changing a few lines of code.

Comment: Thank you for your time. 1. No, we don't use ORM, we use mybatis. 2. I need a solution to find rows to be deleted for any database design. That is database design is not known at compile time.

Comment: So if it's rows deleted, if you built the graph in advance then I am missing the point of the question: the rows are just a sum of the queries for each affected relation, e.g. I am deleting User and cascading to delete his Posts. If I know cascade will go to posts, the rows are just select * from Posts where User = {}.